# Android Studio App Inspector doesn't show databases

Tags: android, database, android-studio, android-room, database-inspector

I tried to open the Database Inspector. For the emulator, it is working correctly, but when I tried to open it for my physical device it shows only the information "Deploy your app to a device running API level 26 or higher, or select a debuggable process to inspect.

I'm using the newest version of Android Studio - Arctic Fox. My phone is using Android 10 - API 29. I'm using the Room database.

I tried "Invalidate and Restart" but it didn't help.

[App Inspector Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BS7s.png)